# EditText данные по умочанию

Tags: java, android

Есть `EditText` в который необходимо вводить только целые числа. В xml файле пометил свойством `inputType="number"`. Как сделать так, что если например пользователь не ввел значение, то в это поле подставилось значение по умолчанию?
Да и еще: как задать диапазон вводимых значений?

Comment: Диапазон вводимых занченйи - пречесление - enum.

Comment: Манипуляции в `EditText` можно отслеживать с помощью интерфейса [`TextWatcher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

Comment: Один вопрос может содержать только одну проблему. Если у вас несколько проблем, задайте новый вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Для значения по умолчанию можно использовать атрибут `android:hint`, это подсказка - которая показывается когда поле пустое.

Забейте в этот атрибут значение по умолчанию и при выходе можно проверять:

```
if(editText.getText()==null || editText.getText().length()==0)
   editText.setText(editText.getHint());
```